# vim what does %s/()()/()/g do

Tags: vim, regex

I used vim for developing one Go script, I intended to replace ()() with (), so I used `%s/()()/()/g`, and then I need help to understand its result:

```
()p()a()c()k()a()g()e() ()s()u()b()
()
()i()m()p()o()r()t()(()
()  ()"()f()m()t()"()
())()
()f()u()n()c() ()S()u()b()F()u()n()(())() (){()
()  ()f()m()t().()P()r()i()n()t()l()n()(()"()i()n() ()S()u()b()F()u()n()"())()
()}()
()f()u()n()c() ()s()u()b()F()u()n()(())() (){()
()  ()f()m()t().()P()r()i()n()t()l()n()(()"()i()n() ()s()u()b()F()u()n()"())()
()}()
```

It seems that a () is inserted around every character (even blank ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses have special meaning in regex. You have to escaped them:

```
%s/\(\)\(\)/()/g
```

What happens with your regex:

`()` stands for a capture group, in this case, it captures nothing because you have nothing inside the parentheses. You have two capture groups that capture nothing, both match empty string. Then you're replacing all these empty string with a pair of parentheses. That's why you finally have pair of parentheses between characters.

[Usefull site for learning regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: what special meaning? what does `()()` mean? and Why is `()()/()` different from `()()/Any`?

Comment: @Tiina: See my edit.